# reverse.code() with mutate_at()

Tags: r, dplyr, psych

My specific challenge is to reverse code some variables using `mutate_at` and `psych::reverse.code()`

I have tried this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reverse.code)
var1<-seq(1,4,1)
var2<-seq(1,4,1)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2)
df %>% 
mutate_at(.vars=vars(matches('[12]?')), .funs=reverse.code, c(-1,-1), .)
```

More generally, I am finding it extraordinarly hard to learn how to combine `mutate_at`, `mutate_all` with `dplyr::recode()`. Is there a good tutorial that someone is aware of? Thank you.

Comment: dplyr's mutate_* functions work with vectorized functions. reverse.code() isn't vectorized. What is the effect of reverse.code you're trying to obtain?

Comment: Hi there, sorry I let this drop. I just want to quickly reverse code some of the variables in a dataset so that 1 because 4 , 2 becomes 3, 3 becomes 2 and 4 becomes 1